# Bizzare issue importing Perl variables from package

Tags: perl

I'm trying to import a variable from a Perl module. I noticed it works when the variable name has length one character and doesn't work when when it has a length longer than one. I literally cannot even the what right now.

I know that you could fill a small stadium with the list Perl gotcha's, but this is a strange one. Why does this happen?

**Example 1)**

mod.pm

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our $aa = 1;

1;
```

test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use mod;

print $aa . "\n";
```

Running it. It fails

```
$ ./test.pl
Variable "$aa" is not imported at ./test.pl line 8.
Global symbol "$aa" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 8.
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

**Example 2)**

mod.pm

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our $a = 1;

1;
```

test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use mod;

print $a . "\n";
```

Running it. It passes

```
./test.pl
1
```

Also, the version info of my interpreter

```
$perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 2 (v5.16.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$a` and `$b` are special variables for [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).  They aren't good choice of variable names for this type of testing.

As for how to get your package importing to work, there are a few steps:

1. Pick a package name that leads with a capital letter, as lower case are meant to be reserved for perl pragmas per [`perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html):

   > Perl informally reserves lowercase module names for "pragma" modules like `integer` and `strict`. Other modules should begin with a capital letter and use mixed case, but probably without underscores due to limitations in primitive file systems' representations of module names as files that must fit into a few sparse bytes
2. Start the module contents with a [`package`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) declaration that matches your file name minus the `.pm`.

These two things change your code to something like the following:

MyMod.pm

```
package MyMod;

use strict;
use warnings;

our $var = 1;

1;
```

test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use MyMod;

print $MyMod::var. "\n";
```

Finally, if you'd like to actually import the variables into the namespace, you'll Just have to look into [`Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html).

Comment: changed to $z and it stopped happening. didn't know that about $a/$b